# Digitar uma palavra e retornar a palavra com as vogais maiúsculas

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
vogais = 'a, e, i, o, u'
palavra = str(input('Digite uma palavra: '))
if palavra.upper() in vogais:
    print(palavra)
else:
    palavra
```

Bem, eu fiz assim mas não deu certo. Não consigo fazer o programa compara e reconhecer só as vogais da palavra e retornar só com as vogais maiúsculas.

Comment: Se for um desafio em inglês, não esqueça de incluir o `y` nas vogais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código não faz muito sentido, está todo "atropelado". Já começa com um problema que não causa erro. Pra que transformar um *string* em *string*?

Pra que separar as vogais com vírgula se você só precisa colocar as vogais para fazer a verificação se a letra se encontra lá?

Se o problema pede para verificar se a letra é vogal porque o teste é feito em cima da palavra toda? E porque converte toda a palavra para maiúscula e depois vê se ela está entre as vogais. Entre as vogais só não, entre as vogais, a vírgula ou espaço em branco. E nunca vai estar por duas razões: você converte para maiúsculo e depois olha onde só tem minúsculas, não tem como dar certo. Mas é pior porque está pedindo para ver se a palavra inteira está entre as vogais, clara que uma palavra não está a não ser que a palavra seja só uma vogal, ou uma sequência que está lá.

Então precisa varrer a palavra pegando letra por letra e testar se a letra, e não a palavra, está entre as vogais, e só as vogais, mais nada. Se estiver, aí você imprime com `upper()`, ou caso contrário deve imprimir também sem mudar a letra, não pode só jogar a variável lá sem dizer que o que fazer com ela.

Do jeito que está vai colocar uma letra em cada linha, precisaria formatar para não pular linha, mas deixo isso como exercício final até porque não deixa claro se precisa colocar tudo na mesma linha.

Tem outras formas mais simples de fazer isso, mas para começar acho que está bom assim:

```
vogais = 'aeiou'
palavra = input('Digite uma palavra: ')
for letra in palavra:
    if letra in vogais:
        print(letra.upper())
    else:
        print(letra)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kK3Pmu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/arvuiwnq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/UpperVowels.py).

Comment: Obrigado! Pela explicação, deu certo, este aí eu tentei de varias maneiras em faze-lo mas não consegui!

Comment: @UberlanTorres veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Apenas como complemento da resposta anterior. Tentei fazer desta maneira...assim o resultado só retorna as vogais em maiúsculo e a palavra é retornada na mesma linha.

```
vogais = 'aeiou'
texto = str(input('Digite uma palavra: '))
lista=[]
for letra in texto:
    if letra in vogais:
        lista.append(letra.upper())
    else:
        lista.append(letra.lower())
junto = ''.join(lista)
print(junto)
```

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar mas primeiro deve se ajudar. Aqui `texto = str(input('Digite uma palavra: '))` essa chamada da função [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-str) é 
desnecessária pois a função [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print) sempre retorna uma string. Em python para fazer com que a função `print()` não pule linha após imprimir basta modificar o argumento nomeado `end`, tornando desnecessária a manipulação de lista, veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/iL1b7B